# I need to calculate the reverse of a number using pointers to functions

Tags: c

So I need to calculate the reverse of a number using pointers in a function. I get junk memory when I run it.Here is what I tried.(When I remove the p ,it works,  I don't get any junk memory but than I can calculate only the remainder ,  I don't get why?)

I m sorry for the earlier post. I read the rules of Stack Overflow.

Here is the code:

```c
int Invers(int x , int *Calculinvers ){
    int rem = 0;
    int p = 1
    while(x!=0){
        rem = x % 10 ;
        *Calculinvers = p*10 + rem;
        x = x / 10;
    }
    return *Calculinvers;
}

int main(){
    int a;
    printf("Introduceti numarul caruia vreti sa-i calculati inversul : \n");
    scanf("%d" , &a);
    int Calcul;
    Invers(a , &Calcul);
    printf("Inversul numarului este  : %d\n" , Calcul);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you read [tour] and [ask] then you should know to provide input and expected/actual output. The code runs and I have no clue what it should be providing. A [mre] requires the literal output, not just some vague description of it.

Comment: Please add: 1) Input 2) Expected output 3) Actual output

Comment: Also, adopt a consistent (as well as safer) "design" of your function. Either you choose to modify the input pointer variable and you sign it `void`, or (preferably in such case I would say) you just assign the result in the `main` function.

Comment: Take some time to explain the function to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). You will always assign `10 + rem` to `Calculinvers` in the loop. So if `x` is `123` then the loop will, in each iteration, assign `13`, `12` and `11` to `*Calculinvers`. It's the last value (`11` in my example) which will be returned.

Comment: `*Calculinvers = p*10 + rem;` --> `*Calculinvers = *Calculinvers*10 + rem;` would be helpful... and on top of that add a proper initialization of `*Calculinvers`

Answer (score 0):

I threw together this, it seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse(int x)
{
    out = 0;
    while (x != 0)
    {
        const int ones = x % 10;
        out *= 10;
        out += ones;
        x /= 10;
    }
    return out;
}

int main(void) {
    const int num[] = { 0, 1, 10, 47, 109, 4711, 1234, 98765432 };
    printf("I got:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof num / sizeof *num; ++i)
    {
        printf(" %d -> %d\n", num[i], reverse(num[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}

It prints:

I got:
 0 -> 0
 1 -> 1
 10 -> 1
 47 -> 74
 109 -> 901
 4711 -> 1174
```

Obviously when we're working with actual integers, trailing zeroes turn into leading zeroes which don't really exist unless we store the original number's length and pad when printing. That's why `10` turns to `1`, for instance.

This is better suited as a pure string-space operation, since then each digit exists as part of the string rather than as part of the representation of a number (which has other conventions).

Update:

If you really want to use pointers, you can of course wrap the above in a more pointery shroud:

```
void reverse_at(int *x)
{
  const int rev = reverse(*x);
  *x = rev;
}
```

but as stated in comments (and hopefully illustrated by my code) a more functional approach where the return value calues the result of a  function is generally more easily understood, safer, and just better.

Comment: I do not see any function pointers here (I do not see any pointers)

Comment: @0___________ Ah, that's a good point I guess. I think the title is broken (the actual body doesn't say function pointers), and the use of pointers was a bit uncalled for but can be handled. I'll edit, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two problems and fixes:

(1)`*Calculinvers` needs to be initialized to 0, or system will give you unexpected value.

(2)Replace `*Calculinvers = p*10 + rem;` to `*Calculinvers = *Calculinvers*10 + rem;` because you did not add the previous value.